# AWS App Runner does not see runtime_environment_variables from Terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-app-runner

Using Terraform with module `aws_apprunner_service` I'm creating AWS App Runner service. [According to documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apprunner_service) I should be able to pass env variables as map.

In my case Service  is created fine, but no any `runtime_environment_variables` are passed to App Runner. All the others variables provided by AWS are present.

App Runner does not have panel for env variables, so I listed all available using NodeJS and console log `console.log(process.env)`

Creating App Runner from AWS console and adding variables works correctly and I can see all default variables and also my custom variables.

My configuration of module

```
resource "aws_apprunner_service" "apprunner" {
  service_name = var.name
  source_configuration {
    authentication_configuration {
      access_role_arn = var.role_arn
    }
    image_repository {
      image_configuration {
        port = var.port
        runtime_environment_variables = {
          "test" = "xxx"
        }
      }
      image_identifier = var.image
      image_repository_type = var.repository_type
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the provider: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/19469

The fix is merged: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/19471/files#diff-30b95f9698f34518d98ef0aa482508ef13b46cb094fe2fa1133019162ceb4908R707-R709

You should wait for a new tag: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/commit/3b05635c2bb9486f5156576b3701746066aa92f8